# For $m$ cubefree, $k^{6}|27m^{2}\Rightarrow k=1 $ or $3$

Tags: number-theory

For $m$ cubefree and $k$ integer $k^{6}|27m^{2}\Rightarrow k=1$ or $3$.

The "1" makes sense from $k^{6}|27m^{2}\Rightarrow ak^{3}=3m$
but not the 3.

So by assuming $9|m$

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that both $k^6$ and $27$ are perfect cubes; if $p$ is a prime divisor of $k$ that is *not* $3$, try concluding that $p^3 | m$.

Comment: @TKM Right: $k$ is a multiple of $3$ (or is $1$). If $k$ is divisible by $9$, then $k^6$ is divisible by an awfully large power of $3$, so $m$....